# How to call graphs not containing vertices which are not in any cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

How are graphs not containing vertices which are not in any cycle called?

I would like to permit bridges in my graph. E.g. I am also interested in the $(V,E)$ graph where $V=\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ and $E=\{A\to B, B\to C, C\to A, C\to D, D\to E, E\to F, F\to D\}$, although $C$ and $D$ cannot be deleted without loosing connectivity.

Comment: I am regularly put on hold, therefore I am surprised at nothing... :D

Answer (score 1):

Graphs with no bridges are called **bridgeless** graphs: [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BridgelessGraph.html), [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)#Bridgeless_graphs).

More generally, you could call them $2$-edge connected graphs: [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-Edge-ConnectedGraph.html), [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph).

If you want every vertex, but not necessarily every edge on some cycle (i.e., bridges are ok), then I cannot recall any common name for this class of graphs, furthermore, [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) doesn't seem have a corresponding sequence (normally it has if a class is common enough).
Thus, even if there is a name (perhaps invented by some author you are referencing), you should define it, just for the reader's convenience.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Definition: a graph is 2-connected "if any vertex were to be removed, the graph will remain connected" (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_graph). I would like to permit those bridges in my graph whose vertices are on some cycle.

Comment: @TobiR You are correct, but then, please make your question more precise. I thought your question was ok, but now that you add more and more changes _in comments_, I might guess why you have been put on hold, and perhaps there were right. Please, ask a single question and be specific.

Comment: E.g. in the (V,E) graph where V={A,B,C,D,E,F} and E={A->B, B->C, C->A, C-> D, D-> E, E-> F, E->D} C and D cannot be deleted without loosing connectivity.

Comment: So the edge (C, D) is a bridge in that graph, right?

Comment: Yes. In the set E, F->D should be instead of E->D as it was signed in the revised question.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like an accurate description of your graphs would be that *every* vertex is part of a cycle, but bridges are allowed. In which case could you say that all bridges are single edges?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you have meant by the question "In which case could you say that all bridges are single edges?". E.g. from the graph V={A,B,C,D,E,F}; E={A->B, B->C, C->A, C->D, D->E, E->F} I would like to delete D, E, F and their edges.

Comment: We can also say that the graph contains such bridges which link two cycles.

Comment: I say that all your bridges are made of a single edge (have a path length of 1) because if they were not there would be a vertex in the bridge that is not part of a cycle. Yes, additionally your single-edge bridges only link cycles. Perhaps you could define bridges that *don't* link two cycles as 'dangling' bridges, and say you have a dangle-bridge-free graph? Sorry, I don't know of any specific terminology for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call them *bridge-free*, for any edge not in a cycle is a bridge.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have looked after the bridge-free graphs, but I have recognized that I should correct my question: how to call graphs not containing VERTICES which are not in any cycle?

Comment: These vertices are special articulation vertices whose deletion doesn't cause the separation (disconnection) of the cycles in the graph.

Comment: (fundamental cycles)

Comment: Although I think everybody would understand what bridge-free graph means, in my opinion your answer is misleading. I think similar mistakes might be a reason for [this](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78275/how-should-i-interpret-english-is-poor-review-when-i-used-a-language-check-ser#comment191930_78280).